# How to split the string value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, split

I have a Table in my database in SQL. This table has a column by this name : Title

Values of this column is : `A + B + CC`  , `D + EEE` , `F + G + H + I` , `HHHH`

I need to split this values and select last index of this values.

How can I select this result : `CC` , `EEE` , `I` , `HHHH`  ?

Comment: Do u need every column (string) last char ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Presumably, the letters can be more than one character.  For this, you need reverse and charindex:

```
select (case when charindex('+', title) > 0
             then right(title, charindex('+', reverse(title))-1)
             else title
        end) as lastone
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select 
     right(Title,case CHARINDEX('+',reverse(Title)) when 0 then LEN(Title) else CHARINDEX('+',reverse(Title))-1 end )
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for your answer. Your answer is correct but answer of gordon-linoffis was faster.